# How to re-post data to the server after a JWT token has been refreshed in Vuejs/Laravel

Tags: vue.js, jwt

I'm building a PWA wherein users log in to enter production data to a form and submit to the server for subsequent processing. I'm using a JWT token to manage the user's status. I'm using Axios interceptors to check that the token is fresh/expired. If the latter, I'm refreshing the token.

My current problem is that I don't know how to automatically resubmit a user's data input if, upon form submission, their token was found to be expired and a new one created.

So, in my bootstrap.js file I have:

```
window.axios.interceptors.response.use((response) => {
  return response;
}, error => {
  let pathUrl = error.config.url;

  if (error.response.status !== 401) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      reject(error);
    });
  }

  if (pathUrl == '/api/question' || error.response.message == 'Your session has expired; please log in again.') {
    getRefreshToken();
    return Promise.reject(error)
  }


});

function getRefreshToken() {
  window.axios.post('/api/auth/refresh')
    .then(response => {
        const token = response.data.access_token
        localStorage.setItem('token', token)
        const JWTtoken = 'Bearer ' + token
        window.axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = JWTtoken;
    })
}
```

The method for submitting the form in the component within which the data are inputted is:

```
  submitData () {        
    let vm = this;
    if (vm.$v.formvar.$pending || vm.$v.formvar.$error) return;
      axios.post('/api/question',vm.formvar)
      .then(res => {  
        this.$router.push('/' + this.$i18n.locale + res.data.path)  
      })          
  },
```

Any help here would be gratefully received.

Thanks/Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `window.axios.request(error.config)` to resend the request

```
if (pathUrl == '/api/question' || error.response.message == 'Your session has expired; please log in again.') {
  return getRefreshToken()
    .then(JWTtoken => {
      error.config.headers['Authorization'] = JWTtoken
      return window.axios.request(error.config)
    })
}
```

`getRefreshToken` should return a Promise

```
function getRefreshToken() {
  return window.axios.post('/api/auth/refresh')
    .then(response => {
      const token = response.data.access_token
      localStorage.setItem('token', token)
      const JWTtoken = 'Bearer ' + token
      window.axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = JWTtoken;
      return JWTtoken
    })
}
```

Comment: Thank you ittus. Just what I needed. Thanks also for highlighting the problem I had in getRefreshToken. Cheers/Tom.